# Point Lighting issue in Webgl

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, lighting

I'm trying to do point lighting on an earth textured sphere from a sun textured 
 sphere, but the light isn't appearing in the correct spot and rotates inversely with the camera. The curious thing is that when I rotate the scene upside down, the point lighting works perfectly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I think it might be a problem with my normals.

[Right side up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU77u.png)

[Upside down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns5tR.png)

Vertex Shader:

```
<!-- Earth Vertex Shader -->
<script id="VertexShader1" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 vPos; //vertex position
attribute vec3 normals;

varying vec3 texCoords;
varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

uniform mat4 uVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;//modelviewmatrix
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;//projectionmatrix

void main(void) {
    vec4 mvPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(vPos, 1.0);
    vec4 lPos = vec4(-20.0,0.0,-20.0,1.0)*uMVMatrix;
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * mvPosition;
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lPos.xyz - mvPosition.xyz);
    vec3 transformedNormal = normalize(vec3(uNormalMatrix * vec4(normals, 0.0)));
    float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, lightDirection), 0.0);
    vLightWeighting = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6) + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * directionalLightWeighting;
    texCoords = normals;
}
</script>
```

Fragment Shader:

```
<!-- Earth Fragment Shader -->
<script id="FragmentShader1" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif

precision mediump float;

varying vec3 texCoords;
varying vec3 vLightWeighting;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void){
    vec2 textureCoords = vec2(atan(texCoords.z, texCoords.x) / (2.0 * 3.14159) + 0.5, asin(texCoords.y) / 3.14159 + 0.5);
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uSampler, textureCoords);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting, textureColor.a);
}


</script>
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should do `uMVMatrix * vec4(-20.0,0.0,-20.0,1.0);` instead of `vec4(-20.0,0.0,-20.0,1.0) * uMVMatrix;`

Comment: Will that actually change anything?

Comment: Wow that fixed it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Like I suggested in comments, you are multiplying matrices like this in other places: `matrix * vector` but your light position is multiplied differently: `vector * matrix`. To use the same convention, replace this line:

```
vec4(-20.0,0.0,-20.0,1.0) * uMVMatrix;
```

with:

```
uMVMatrix * vec4(-20.0,0.0,-20.0,1.0);
```